# Retrieve Site collection administrators from SharePoint Online using C# client object model

Tags: development, sharepoint-online

Can someone please suggest on how to fetch all the sitecollection administrators from SharePoint online(Office 365 SharePoint) using c# client object model.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Get all sitecollection administrators using C# client object model :

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext("http://..."))
    {
        Site site = clientContext.Site;                
        Web web = clientContext.Web;                
        UserCollection coll = web.SiteUsers;
        clientContext.Load(coll);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();        
        foreach (User user in coll)
        {
           if (user.IsSiteAdmin)
           {
              // 'user' is SiteAdmin
           }
        }
     }
```

Comment: User is asking for C# Client Object model not Server Object Model. Above code uses Server Object Model.

Comment: `Web.Users` property is not present in client object model.

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var clientContext = new ClientContext("http://aissp2013:90"))
    {
        Site site = clientContext.Site;                
        Web web = clientContext.Web;                
        UserCollection coll = web.SiteUsers;
        clientContext.Load(coll);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach (User user in coll)
        {               
            if (user.IsSiteAdmin)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(user.LoginName);
            }                    
        }
    }

    Console.Read();
}
```